# Exasol_Error: I keep getting Exasol connection error timed out

Tags: python, database-connection, talend, dbvisualizer, exasol

I am trying to connect to my Exasol SaaS database, I tried via these tools(TALEND, DBVISUALIZER, POWERBI) and via python but I cannot connect and I keep getting the same error.

I saw another post on Exasol community https://community.exasol.com/t5/discussion-forum/exaconnectionfailederror/m-p/8049#M1855 of this type of error but it doesn't explain exactly what was done to fix the error. I tried via the ODBC Data Source administrator(64-bit) too but still the same error. Maybe its an connection issue with my pc self but I'm not sure or maybe I am just inserting wrong values I don't know.

Oh the values I inserted are the recommended ones from what Exasol docs states and I have removed anything about proxy or vpn.

I put my errors under. I tried via different devices and I get the same error I really don't know what I can do any more, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Note: I am using the Exasol SaaS database and I am currently on the trial mode so I am not sure if this is limiting me.

```
**Errors: **
Error message odbc exasol: [EXASOL][EXASolution driver]connection attempt timed out.

Error message Talend : Connection failure. You must change the Database Settings.
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.exasol.jdbc.ConnectFailed: connect timed out ->
Caused by: com.exasol.jdbc.ConnectFailed: connect timed out

Error message pyexasol : socket.timeout: timed out

Error message dbvisualizer : java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out com.exasol.jdbc.ConnectFailed: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out

Error message Power BI desktop : Details: "ODBC: ERROR [HYT00][EXASOL][EXASolution driver]Connection attempt timed out."
```

```
My applications versions:
DbVisualizer Free 14.0.1 (build: 3540)
Talend Open Studio Data integration(8.0.1.2021119_1610)
java version -> jdk-16.0.02
Power BI -> Version: 2.110.1085.0 64-bit (October 2022)
ODBC : exasolodbc x64 7.1.14
JDBC : exasoljdbc 7.1.14
Python: python 3.8.10 -> pyexasol : 0.25.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did more digging. actually I have no idea what the issue was.

Talend:
I made a connection via JDBC in Talend with the help of exasol-support. The DBType Exasol in talend doesn't work for some reason, its not known if it's talend side or Exasol side, maybe this will be updated in the future. Just remember in the jdbc url type this: "jdbc:exa:yourconnectionstring", don't forget the "exa".

PowerBI:
I tried the connection string with fingerprint method that worked for me. Just put the fingerprint with the connection string and it should connect.
https://exasol.my.site.com/s/article/PowerBI-Encryption-Fingerprint-Issue-in-Exasol-7-1?language=en_US

DBvisualizer:
I had a wrong in connection string.

Python:
I had a wrong in connection string.

Hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: for anyone who sees this, take a look at this solution, this will be the correct answer: https://community.talend.com/s/question/0D55b000087hXb4CAE/exasol-database-connection-not-working?language=en_US

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the client is not able to reach the host for some reason. Try the following:

1. Make sure the database is still online (they auto-shutdown after 2 hours if there is no activity by default)
2. Check that the IP Address of the host you are connecting with is added to the allow list in the SaaS UI. (see the [docs](https://docs.exasol.com/saas/administration/network_security.htm))
3. Check if your host is able to reach the host and port specified in the SaaS UI (for example using telnet on port 8563). Maybe some firewall is preventing access to the database?

Comment: hello @fortnico, 1 and 2 check. I tried 3, telnet XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 8563 -> returns "Connecting To XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX...Could not open connection to the host, on port 8563: Connect failed" then I tried, telnet XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8563 -> returns "Connecting To XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8563...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed". I did make a rule in/outbound so that port 8563 can have all connection. I tried to ping the server it gives me "Reply from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX: Destination host unreachable.".

Comment: Are you using a company machine? You could add an IP address of a personal machine and try the telnet from there. If it works from your personal machine, probably there is some company setting blocking it (in my company I can only connect via Wifi for example, not ethernet). If neither are working, I would contact support to look at the allow list settings